# Angular 2 child routes freezez application

Tags: typescript, angular

Hi I am trying to create child routs for my angular app here is what I have so far:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {CommercifyComponent} from './commercify.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(CommercifyComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);

@Component({
    selector: 'commercify',
    templateUrl: './app/commercify.view.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})
@RouteConfig([     
    { path: '/Catalog/...', name: 'Catalog', component: CatalogComponent, useAsDefault: true },     
])            
export class CommercifyComponent {}
```

This is **commercify.view.html**

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is **CatalogComponent**:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';
import {TemplatesComponent} from './components/templates.component';

@Component({
templateUrl: './app/catalog/catalog.view.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/Templates', name: 'Templates', component: TemplatesComponent, useAsDefault: true },
])
export class CatalogComponent {

}
```

This is **catalog view**:

```
<nav>Navigation will be here</nav>
<router-outlet name="Catalog"></router-outlet>
```

This is template component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'templates',
    template: 'This is templates component'
})
export class TemplatesComponent implements OnInit {
    private templateDataService: TemplateDataService;

    public settings = <CatalogViewModel.TemplateSettings>{
        templatesToSkip: 0,
        templatesToTake: 0
    }

    constructor(templateDataService: TemplateDataService) {
        this.templateDataService = templateDataService;
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.getTemplates();
    }

    private getTemplates() {
        this.templateDataService.getAllByRange(this.settings.templatesToSkip, this.settings.templatesToTake).subscribe(x => {
            console.log(x)
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I load the page is freezing.

I am assuming this is happening because I have added one router-outet in commercify.view and one router-outlet in catalog.view. If I remove the second router-outlet the following the application the displayed root gets set to

`http://localhost:6554/Catalog/Templates`

This is correct but but it is not calling the TemplateComponent code. Furthermore I want to be able to specify where the template.view code gets displayed caose the parent category will have a menu structure.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should only be added to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])` but not on each component, otherwise a new instance of all injected types is created for each component even when a global instance should be passed in.

Comment: I did that but still the TemplateComponent code is not being executed

Comment: `<rotuer-outlet></rotuer-outlet>` should be `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Is this only in your question or also in your application code?

Comment: It is also in the application ... I added a name to the second router-outlet and apparently it is nto freezing the application anymore I will update the code now

Comment: But `TemplateComponent` is still not added?

Comment: You shouldn't add a `name="Catalog"` to `<router-outlet>` this is only for aux-routes. There must be one, and only one `<router-outlet>` without a `name`

Comment: Ok then how do I tell the RouteConfig in CatalogComponent where to add the html from the TemplateComponent ?

Comment: When a component has route configurations and a `<router-outlet>` then the component is added there. If there are child routes, the added component also needs to have a `<router-outlet>`. There can always only be one `<router-outlet>` for a hierarchy level and there the component is added.

Comment: After moving the ROUTER_PROVIDERS in bootstrap I noticed that now the CatalogComponent is not being called anymore

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? It's quite difficult to debug from just looking at the snippets in your question.

Comment: The initial suggestion is what fixed my problem I had some aditional TS error and my code was not generating I did not realise at the time thatx for the quick responses

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!